# truffle-plugin.json not found in the solidity-coverage plugin package

Tags: npm, truffle, erc20

When executing
`truffle run verify --network Mumbai MyContract@0x4F27354a7476854Bb96116912035ef60BC363f75`

I receive the error message:
**truffle-plugin.json not found in the solidity-coverage plugin package!**

My node modules have solidity-coverage installed, as well as my global environment.

**IN MAC TERMINAL:**

- node version: v18.17.0
- npm version: 9.6.7
- Truffle v5.11.1 (core: 5.11.1)
- Ganache v7.9.0
- Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
- Node v18.17.0
- Web3.js v1.10.0
- Compiler Version: 0.8.19

**IN VS CODE:**
npm list -g
/usr/local/lib
├── corepack@0.18.0
├── npm@9.6.7
├── solidity-coverage@0.8.4
├── truffle-contract-size@2.0.1
├── truffle-plugin-verify@0.6.4
├── truffle@5.11.1

Any tips on what I can do?

It should find the plug-in however nothing is working.

Comment: I currently have the same problem. Have you now figured out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`solidity-coverage` plugin moved it's support to hardhat

https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage/releases/tag/v0.8.0

> ⚠️ This version requires Hardhat >= 2.11.0 (Ethereum Merge)
>
> Note to Truffle users: solidity-coverage for Truffle is moving to its own repository and published under a different name (details soon...).

You'll need to install `0.7.x` versions again :)

```
npm i -D solidity-coverage@0.7.22
```